# Simple image rotation

Tags: java, image, user-interface, java-2d

I am making a game in Java. I made a planet seen from outer space and I want to make it appear like the planet is slowly rotating. But I don't know how to rotate a image. I need a simple command that rotates my image 1 degree around its own center once. Any help?

---

This is what I want to do:
[Image](http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/266/examplea.png/)

Comment: *"Simple image rotation"*  By 'simple' DYM spoon feed the answer to you?  [What have you tried?](http://www.whathaveyoutried.com/)

Comment: whats your frontend? html/html5/android/2dgraphics?

Comment: Use an `AffineTransform` (presuming Java 2D).  Here is an example of [animated rotation](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11117371/418556).  It uses shapes and areas, but the principle is the same.

Comment: I looked at your example but it seems that this will rotate the entire image. I don't want my background to rotate only the planet. As seen http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/266/examplea.png/

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at these tutorials:

- [Java2D: Have Fun With Affine Transform](http://www.javalobby.org/java/forums/t19387.html)
- [Coordinate Translations and Rotations: Example Code](http://www.apl.jhu.edu/~hall/java/Java2D-Tutorial.html#Java2D-Tutorial-Transforms-Example1)
- [Transforming Shapes, Text, and Images](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/2d/advanced/transforming.html)

Comment: Might be a stupid question but does it really have to be that complicated? isn't there a command like image.rotate(degrees)?

Comment: No, but you can extend `Image` and add to it method `rotate(degrees)` and use it.

Answer (score 0):

What you are describing is not rotating an image, but changing an image to represent a 3D rotation of the object in the image.

Ideally you wouldn't be working with this as an image but rather as a 3D object with a different camera angle.  Then you would simply rotate the camera around the object and display the resulting image to the user.

However if you're set on doing this as an image, then you need to create a different images representing various states of rotation of your planet and have a separate thread that would replace the displayed image with the next one in sequence, at repeated intervals.  Search the web for "java image animation" - there are plenty of tutorials on how to do this.

If you want to rotate an image in 2d space, you can use something like this:

```
Image image = ...
Graphics2D g2d = ...; // 
g2d.translate(170, 0); // If needed
g2d.rotate(1);  // Rotate the image by 1 radian
//or g2d.rotate(180.0/3.14); to rotate by 1 degree
g2d.drawImage(image, 0, 0, 200, 200, observer);
```

Comment: I think you misunderstood me. Sorry for not being clear enough. This is what i want to do: http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/266/examplea.png/

Comment: Is your planet a separate image from the background star field?  If no, then you still have to do what I described in the second part.  If your star field is separate, then you can easily rotate the image using java-2d.

Comment: It is a separate image. Will take a look at java 2d

Comment: ah. So the g2d.translate needs to be the center X and Y cordinate of the planet right?

Comment: I think so.  Just give it a try.