# flower shaped imageview in android

Tags: java, android

i am using the following code to draw different shaped imageviews, (like diamond , star etc).
but how can i draw a flower shaped imageview.?
any help in apriciated.!

```
public static Bitmap getRoundedCroppedBitmap(Bitmap bitmap, int radius) 
{

Bitmap finalBitmap;
if (bitmap.getWidth() != radius || bitmap.getHeight() != radius)
    finalBitmap = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bitmap, radius, radius, false);
else
    finalBitmap = bitmap;

Bitmap output = Bitmap.createBitmap(finalBitmap.getWidth(),
        finalBitmap.getHeight(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
Canvas canvas = new Canvas(output);

Paint paint = new Paint();
final Rect rect = new Rect(0, 0, finalBitmap.getWidth(),
        finalBitmap.getHeight());

Point point1_draw = new Point(finalBitmap.getWidth()/2, 0);
Point point2_draw = new Point(0, finalBitmap.getHeight());
Point point3_draw = new Point(finalBitmap.getWidth(), finalBitmap.getHeight());

Path path = new Path();
path.moveTo(point1_draw.x, point1_draw.y);
path.lineTo(point2_draw.x, point2_draw.y);
path.lineTo(point3_draw.x, point3_draw.y);
path.lineTo(point1_draw.x, point1_draw.y);
path.close();
canvas.drawARGB(0, 0, 0, 0);
paint.setColor(Color.parseColor("#BAB399"));
canvas.drawPath(path, paint);    
paint.setXfermode(new PorterDuffXfermode(Mode.SRC_IN));
canvas.drawBitmap(finalBitmap, rect, rect, paint);

    return output;
}
```

[like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VmkqC.png)

Answer (score 0):

I haven't already worked with custom shapes, but I've found a post from StackOverflow, which can be useful:

> Here is my attempt - using a rotate transform anchored on the center
>   of the flower shape.
>
> [image]
>
> ```
> import java.awt.*;
> import java.awt.geom.*;
> import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
> import javax.swing.*;
>
> public class DaisyDisplay {
>
>   DaisyDisplay() {
>       BufferedImage daisy = new BufferedImage(
>               200,200,BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);
>       Graphics2D g = daisy.createGraphics();
>       g.setColor(Color.GREEN.darker());
>       g.fillRect(0, 0, 200, 200);
>       Daisy daisyPainter = new Daisy();
>       daisyPainter.paint(g);
>       g.dispose();
>
>       JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, new JLabel(new ImageIcon(daisy)));
>   }
>
>   public static void main(String[] args) {
>       SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
>           @Override
>           public void run() {
>               new DaisyDisplay();
>           }
>       });
>   }
> }
>
> class Daisy {
>
>   public void paint(Graphics2D g) {
>       Area daisyArea = getDaisyShape();
>       g.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING, 
>               RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);
>
>       paintDaisyPart(g,daisyArea);
>       g.setTransform(AffineTransform.getRotateInstance(
>               Math.PI*1/8,
>               100,100));
>       paintDaisyPart(g,daisyArea);
>       g.setTransform(AffineTransform.getRotateInstance(
>               Math.PI*3/8,
>               100,100);
>       paintDaisyPart(g,daisyArea);
>       g.setTransform(AffineTransform.getRotateInstance(
>               Math.PI*2/8,
>               100,100));
>       paintDaisyPart(g,daisyArea);
>   }
>
>   public void paintDaisyPart(Graphics2D g, Area daisyArea) {
>       g.setClip(daisyArea);
>
>       g.setColor(Color.YELLOW);
>       g.fillRect(0, 0, 200, 200);
>
>       g.setColor(Color.YELLOW.darker());
>       g.setClip(null);
>       g.setStroke(new BasicStroke(3));
>       g.draw(daisyArea);
>   }
>
>   public Area getDaisyShape() {
>       Ellipse2D.Double core = new Ellipse2D.Double(70,70,60,60);
>
>       Area area = new Area(core);
>       int size = 200;
>       int pad = 10;
>       int petalWidth = 50;
>       int petalLength = 75;
>
>       // left petal
>       area.add(new Area(new Ellipse2D.Double(
>               pad,(size-petalWidth)/2,petalLength,petalWidth)));
>       // right petal
>       area.add(new Area(new Ellipse2D.Double(
>               (size-petalLength-pad),(size-petalWidth)/2,petalLength,petalWidth)));
>       // top petal
>       area.add(new Area(new Ellipse2D.Double(
>               (size-petalWidth)/2,pad,petalWidth,petalLength)));
>       // bottom petal
>       area.add(new Area(new Ellipse2D.Double(
>               (size-petalWidth)/2,(size-petalLength-pad),petalWidth,petalLength)));
>
>       return area;
>   }
> }
> ```

Read whole conversation: [Shapes combination in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10881259/shapes-combination-in-java)

Hope it help